# Bookmarklet to load current page without JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, mobile-safari, bookmarklet

I would like to have a bookmarklet to load the current page/tab without its scripts, as if the browser had JavaScript disabled in its settings. Is it possible?

It would work a bit like this Chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/toggle-javascript/cidlcjdalomndpeagkjpnefhljffbnlo

But without the "toggle" function, i.e., the bookmarklet wouldn't enable JavaScript.

I like that extension and I would love to have something similar on iOS. It is possible to disable JavaScript in Safari, but it's annoying to open Settings every time I want to load a page without the scripts.

I thought a bookmarklet might allow me to quickly load the current page without it scripts, but I don't know if it's possible. Feel free to suggest other workarounds (maybe using Shortcuts/Workflow?).

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a [userscript](https://tampermonkey.net/): `fetch` the current page, parse the response text into a document, remove all `<script>` tags in the document, then open a new window with `window.open()`, and populate its `<head>` and `<body>` with the cleaned document's `<head>` and `<body>`:

```
window.openPageWithoutScripts = async function() {
  const resp = await fetch(window.location.href);
  const text = await resp.text();
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
  doc.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => script.remove());
  const w = window.open();
  w.document.head.innerHTML = doc.head.innerHTML;
  w.document.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
};
```

Then, whenever you want to open the current page without any scripts, open the console and type in `openPageWithoutScripts()`.

This strips out `<script>` tags, but not inline handlers, which are less predictable and harder to get rid of (though, luckily, they're bad practice and are generally rarer).

To also strip out inline handlers, create an array of all possible events, then iterate over them and `querySelectorAll` elements with those handlers, and remove the attribute:

```
window.openPageWithoutScripts = async function() {
  const resp = await fetch(window.location.href);
  const text = await resp.text();
  const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html');
  doc.querySelectorAll('script').forEach(script => script.remove());
  const eventNames = ['click', 'load', 'error']; // etc
  eventNames.forEach((e) => {
    const onEventName = 'on' + e;
    document.querySelectorAll(`[${onEventName}]`).forEach((elm) => {
      elm.removeAttribute(onEventName);
    });
  });
  const w = window.open();
  w.document.head.innerHTML = doc.head.innerHTML;
  w.document.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
};
```